# Hidden rows in SSRS and Exporting to Excel issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report that has 3 expandable columns. I have a condition in one of the rows that says the following for the hidden property:

```
=IIF(Parameters!GroupBy.Value = "Fleet", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Basically this is saying that if the parameter picked is Fleet then the hidden value is set to true otherwise its set to false. It looks perfect in the report preview but then when I export it to excel it shows these rows no matter what....

Whats the deal?

Comment: The deal is, that exporting from SSRS is pretty poor. On occasion I have had to develop 2 reports against the same proc: one with zero formatting for Excel, and one with all the tables/graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience hidinng rows in excel doesn't work well. I suggest you instead use the expression to filter out the column from your dataset. It has the same effect but works better in excel.

In terms of filtering, you can either filter it in your sql, in the dataset, or in your table/list/chart.